# Heading number and title on separate lines with different styles in office 2013

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office

I'm trying to achieve the following in office 2013:
[image]

Basically I want the heading number to be on top of the actual title. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

There is no obvious way to achieve this directly.

The best I've been able to come up with is to create a custom command via VBA that inserts a set sequence variable `{{seq h1}}` for example along with the text and then reformats automatically. Not sure how this would appear in the TOC though so not ideal.